# Google Play Store warn to update firebase-crashlytics in react-native mobile app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have developed my mobile application in react-native, where I have used `@react-native-firebase/crashlytics` to track crashes in my application. Everything is working fine.

In my last upload `.aab` to PlayStore, google warn me to update firebase Crashlytics and they will not support after march.
Here is the message I got from them.

> We detected an issue in this version of the Crashlytics Android SDK. We strongly recommend either using v18.2.13 or earlier or upgrading to v18.3.1+. For more info see: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/4223
>
> Starting from March 18, 2023 00:00 (UTC) you won't be able to release new versions which contain this SDK version.

I have used latest `@react-native-firebase/crashlytics` npm in my project, but still it showing the same sdk in my android project. Check in screenshot.

[image]

How to I upgrade Android firebase-crashlytics-SDK ?

Comment: Have you tried running "npm upgrade @react-native-firebase/crashlytics " ?

Comment: yes I have already tried